# How can I reset my nix environment to the original user profile?

Tags: nix, nixos

I believe I ran `nix-env -if example.nix` which changed my nix environment.

How can I undo this action?

I'm trying to run a application that is specified in my nixos config (`/etc/nixos/*`), however it no longer seems available (within the `$PATH`).

---

Seems it might be `nix-env --switch-profile /nix/var/nix/profiles/default` (according to https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-profiles) ?

Comment: Re: "undo this action" -- `nix-env --rollback`, if that's the most recent operation you did.

Comment: You might also want to run `nix-env --list-generations` to get a rough idea of which generation you want to go back to.

Comment: And you can pick a particular generation via `nix-env -G gen-number-goes-here`. If you mess up your config this comes in handy. Once you go back to a previous generation any subsequent changes to _that_ generation will create a newest generation and you can continue on from there. It is great being able to rollback.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I run `nix-env -e '*'` to remove all packages from my profile installed via `nix-env` regularly and move anything I want to use into `environment.systemPackages` so all my packages are tracked in my nixos configuration declaratively. As for debugging why the application specified in your `configuration.nix` isn't in your path, an application specified in your `configuration.nix` should be symlinked to `/run/current-system/sw/bin`, so the first thing would be to check that the binary you're looking for is listed in there and second that is in your `$PATH`.